# Instantiating a new struct from pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is part of a homework assignment that I've benn struggeling with for days now.
So we define this struct

```
typedef enum { male = 0, female } gender;

struct person {
char name[30];
gender genderValue;
int age;
float weight;};
```

Now, we are given this function

```
int add(char* name, char* genderValueString, int age, float weight){}
```

And we are asked to construct a new person inside that function.
I tried different methods but keep getting errors and can't even get the name right.

```
struct person newperson = {.name = *newname, //...rest of code..};
```

only read the first character and ignores the rest.
How do I get the values passed into a newperson person.

This doesn't work either :

```
char newname[30];
strcpy_s(newname, 30, name);
struct person newperson = { .name = newname //...}
```

Comment: To copy `char` arrays (or "strings") in C, you need to loop and copy each `char` individually.

Comment: Take out `newname` and `.name = newname`, and use `strcpy` into `.name` after the initializer

Answer (score 0):

There's two problems:

The first is that you *dereference* the pointer variable `newname`. That gives you the value the pointer is pointing to, which is really just the first letter of the string.

The second problem is that you can't initialize an array with a pointer or another array. You have to *copy* arrays. For string you should use [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) (or `strcpy_s` if it's available).

Comment: This doesn't work either :
 `char newname[30];

     strcpy_s(newname, 30, name);

     struct person newperson = { .name = newname //...}`

Comment: @NidhalSelmi That's because the structure `name` member is an array. You need to copy to *that* array.